# Static IP address on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, static-ip

I want to have the ability to edit my static IP on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop using only CLI. However, when I do that I have two IP addresses for the same machine: one is assigned by DHCP server and the other taken from /etc/network/interfaces.

**Here's the process**

Edited /etc/network/interfaces and added static IP. Contents of the file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.0.29
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Stopped and removed Ubuntu Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```

Restarted networking service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Also tried to restart interface itself:

```
ifdown enp0s3 && ifup enp0s3
```

Tried to reboot the machine, didn't help either.

The result is that I have two IP addresses assigned to my machine. I even tried to ssh to both of them and it's really the same machine..
First one is assigned from DHCP server:

```
ping 192.168.0.189
PING 192.168.0.189 (192.168.0.189): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.189: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.341 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.189: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.265 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.189: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.315 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.189: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.395 ms
```

Second one is assigned by editing /etc/network/interfaces

```
ping 192.168.0.29
PING 192.168.0.29 (192.168.0.29): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.29: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.380 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.29: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.742 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.29: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.313 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.29: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.308 ms
```

ifconfig produces the same result before and after making the edits:

```
ifconfig -a
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f6:b1:d3  
          inet addr:192.168.0.189  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1310 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2496671 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:124720 (124.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:19145 (19.1 KB)  TX bytes:19145 (19.1 KB)
```

So what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps aux|grep dhclient` show something? if yes, then `killall dhclient` and restart network.

Comment: `ps aux|grep dhclient` showed some processes, so I used `killall dhclient`. After doing so I lost internet connection and had to restart networking service to get it back. For now it seems to work only with one IP address. That's good outcome. But is this the right way to do it? Shouldn't `apt-get purge network-manager` kill all the processes related to it?

Comment: No. [Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720571/which-program-invokes-dhclient-on-debian-squeeze)